# Is there an easy way to bucket saved files with a case statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create code to examine a column of names. I want to bucket files into three categories (names that fall between A-G, H-P, Q-Z).

I figure a case statement before I save off the file is the right approach, but not sure if I need to utilize an `instr` function or something of the sort.

Here's a crude example of how I have it set up currently (commented out the case statements).

```
        Dim BASEPATH_1 As String, BASEPATH_2 As String, BASEPATH_3 As String


        BASEPATH_1 = "C:\Users\A-G\"
        BASEPATH_2 = "C:\Users\H-P\"
        BASEPATH_3 = "C:\Users\Q-Z\"


        Select Case wb.Cells(i, 8)
        'Case i.value is betwen "A-G"
            wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH_1 & _
            ValidFileName(Login & "_" & Last & "_PrePlanning File.xlsx")
        'Case i.value is betwen "H-P"
            wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH_2 & _
            ValidFileName(Login & "_" & Last & "_PrePlanning File.xlsx")
        'Case i.value is betwen "Q-Z"
            wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH_3 & _
            ValidFileName(Login & "_" & Last & "_PrePlanning File.xlsx")
        Case Else
        End Select
```

Full Code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Data, Last, Login, lvl2mgr
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
    Dim Dest As Range
    Dim BASEPATH1 As String, BASEPATH2 As String, BASEPATH3 As String, strNewPath As String


    BASEPATH1 = "C:\A-G"
    BASEPATH2 = "C:\H-P"
    BASEPATH3 = "C:\Q-Z"

    Set wb = Workbooks("Preplanning_Template.xlsx")

    Set Dest = wb.Sheets("Manager File").Range("A3")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planning File")
        Data = .Range("BP2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    wb.Activate
    Call Ludicrous(True)

    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)

        If Data(i, 7) <> Login Then
            If i > 1 Then
                Dest.Select
                wb.Sheets(1).Cells.WrapText = False
                    Call FillDown
                    Call FillColors
                wb.Cells.Columns("A:BP").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                wb.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                wb.Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1
            End If

           Select Case Asc(Cells(i, 8).Value)

                Case 65 To 71 'A-G
                    wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH1 & _
                    ValidFileName(Login & "_" & Last & "_PrePlanning File.xlsx")

                Case 72 To 80 'H-P
                    wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH2 & _
                    ValidFileName(Login & "_" & Last & "_PrePlanning File.xlsx")

                Case 81 To 90 'Q-Z
                    wb.SaveCopyAs BASEPATH3 & _
                    ValidFileName(Login & "_" & Last & "_PrePlanning File.xlsx")

            Case Else
            End Select

            With wb.Sheets("Manager File")
                .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
                .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Interior.Color = xlNone
            End With

            Login = Data(i, 7)
            Last = Data(i, 8)


            j = 0
        End If

        a = 0
        For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Dest.Offset(j, a) = Data(i, k)
            a = a + 1
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next

    SaveCopy wb, Login, Last

    Call Ludicrous(False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Asc` on the cell value.

Comment: @BigBen Hey, sorry, I've never used Asc function, could you further elaborate?

Comment: @NidenK - what's wrong with Google or Excel help?!

Comment: @bigben something like: `Case i.value = Asc("A-G")` ?

Comment: What is a sample value in `wb.Cells(i, 8)`? Does it begin with `A` to `Z`, or is the letter in question somewhere in the middle?

Comment: The column is a list of named, formatted `last name, first name`. Is it because there is a comma delimiter in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Asc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/asc-function) here, which from the documentation:

> Returns an `Integer` representing the character code corresponding to the first letter in a string

```
Select Case Asc(wb.Cells(i, 8).Value)
    Case 65 to 71 'A to G
        ...
    Case 72 to 80 'H to P
        ...
    Case 81 to 90 'Q to Z
        ...
End Select
```

Note, you should check if the cell isn't empty too. Wrap this in `If Not IsEmpty(wb.Cells(i, 8).Value) Then...End If`

Second note, `wb`, if that is indeed a `Worksheet` variable, is pretty misleading - try `ws`. If `wb` is a `Workbook`, then you need a sheet reference before `Cells`.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid procedure call on this line: `Select Case Asc(Cells(i, 8).Value)`. I switched out the `wb` object and still am getting it.

Comment: @NidenK When that happens, what is the value of `wb.Cells(i, 8).Value`?  The most likely cause of that error is an empty string (i.e. `ASC("")`)

Comment: @NidenK see the last sentence. Thanks Chronocidal.

Comment: If `wb` is a workbook you will need a sheet reference in the middle.

Comment: @Chronocidal it's just a name (for the sake of anonymity, well call them `Mason, Thomas`)

Comment: @NidenK - wrap the `Select Case` in the check for whether the cell is empty or not.

Comment: @BigBen I can see in the locals window that the value is in fact a name

Comment: `Mason, Thomas` works for me. I can't replicate that error. Maybe [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58880626/edit) your question with the revised code you are using. As a side check, `? Asc("Mason, Thomas")` in the Immediate Window gives you `77` :)

Comment: @BigBen I got rid of the workbook reference and am still getting the error. It's referencing the active sheet, which is correct in my case. Nothing seems to be incorrect in the locals window, no clue what's causing this error

Comment: Hey, I'm so sorry, I figured out what was happening. So the cell was empty because it hadn't referenced the variable `Last` which depended upon the `Data(I,8)` value. It was empty until it was assigned later in the code. My mistake, your solution works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Two options below that are easier to read than an ASCII conversion

```
Dim fullName as string
Dim firstChar as string

    fullName = ws.Cells(i, 8).value
    firstChar = left(fullName,1) '<-- assume not empty string


Select Case True 
    Case fullName Like "[A-G]*"
        ...
    Case fullName Like "[H-P]*"
        ...
    Case fullName Like "[Q-Z]*"
        ...
    Case fullName Else
        ... ' Bad value entered
End Select

Select Case firstChar 
    Case "A" To "G"
        ...
    Case "H" To "P"
        ...
    Case "Q" To "Z"
        ...
    Case Else
        ... ' Bad value entered
End Select
```